# Datatable processing slow

Tags: datatable, datatables

I have a large chunk of data populating in datatables on the page. Which is freezing the browser.
I found a solution for this using meta tag name "SKYPE_TOOLBAR", which has solved the problem. I want to know....

How does this helps fasten the process of large data in Data tables? Is it safe to use it in the project?

```
<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE" />
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with dataTables itself. This is because Skype Toolbar is parsing all content in the table in an attempt to decorate or beautify phone numbers. A very, **very** bad thing for any modern app or webpage, that dynamically updates the DOM (as dataTables does).  `<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE" />`
 turn that "feature" off.

Comment: thanks @davidkonrad . Its bit strange that it stops freezing. Thanks for your reply.